# Extract list of sheet names in message box where IF condition is False within a for loop through multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code which loops through multiple sheets. With each sheet there is a "IF Condition" & when true, creates charts, else loops to next sheet. Once executed this code, the message box showing the sheet name pops up "one by one" where the IF condition fails. I need two message boxes.

1. A msg box which puts all the sheet names one below the other, where IF Condition if False.
2. Similarly, in the 2nd msgbox, I would like to get a list of sheets where IF is true and charts generated successfully.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thankyou.

```
Sub DemandSupply()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
Dim chtobj As ChartObject, srs As Series
Dim txtBox As String

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
txtBox = WS_Count - 3

For I = 4 To WS_Count
    Sheets(I).Activate

    If Cells(11, 2).Value > 0 Then

            'My code for generating charts

    Else: MsgBox "Sub-block " & ActiveSheet.Name & " has no legal supply!"
    End If

    Next I

    MsgBox "Yay! It's done!"  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code :)

```
    Sub DemandSupply()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
    Dim chtobj As ChartObject, srs As Series
    Dim txtBox As String

    Dim true_msg As String
    Dim false_msg As String

    Dim sh As Variant
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Cells(11, 2).Value > 0 Then
            'My code for generating charts
            true_msg = true_msg & sh.Name & vbNewLine  'IF is true and charts generated successfully.
            Else
            false_msg = false_msg & sh.Name & vbNewLine  'IF Condition if False
        End If
    Next sh

    MsgBox "List of sheet condition True:" & vbNewLine & true_msg 'adapt the message
    MsgBox "List of sheet condition False :" & vbNewLine & false_msg 'adapt the message

End Sub
```

Comment: I think any numeric value other than 0 is counted as TRUE, so just `If sh.Cells(11,2) Then` would also work.  Not quite as clear though I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot JC.....Worked for me. I had retained looping sheets through sheet index though, as I do not want charts for the first 3 sheets.

Comment: Great! glad to help you